# Lookup data is not populating in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

in salesforce there is one field A in case object, it is lookup field dataype and it is having relationship with user object. when i am searching for user name i am getting an error
[image]

"Select an option from the picklist or remove the search term." how to resolve this

how to get the users data in that field